# Puppet MySQL disable root user login without password

Tags: mysql, puppet, puppetlabs-mysql

I have been over several threads for issues related to puppetlabs-mysql module in last few hours to get a workaround on my issue.

MySQL installation on my agent node with this module is enabling the root user login without any password. But I see the credentials has been set for the root user, and can login using those credentials also.

What difference should I make in my manifest to disable MySQL password-less root login?

Manifest applied,

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  root_password    => 'rootpassword',
  override_options => { 'mysqld' => { 'max_connections' => '1024' } }
}
```

Comment: its probably setting the password for `'root'@'localhost'` and not `'root'@'%'`

Comment: Thanks @ptierno . Any idea on the manifest part for the same?

Comment: Just use the mysql_user resource: (sorry for the broken formatting)

`mysql_user { 'root@%':
       ensure        => present,
      password_hash => mysql_password('rootpassword'),
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to as passwordless login is most probably [.my.cnf](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql/blob/master/manifests/server/root_password.pp#L31) saving the password in an [optionfile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).

So by setting $mysql::server::create_root_my_cnf to false you would disable this.

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  root_password    => 'rootpassword',
  create_root_my_cnf => false,
  override_options => { 'mysqld' => { 'max_connections' => '1024' } }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That manifest will create  .my.cnf under my root(shell) user. So that means, it prompt for mysql root password from other shell users.

I have tried your example. It works, thank you.
But the thing with this is, it will throw an error on further user,db creations.  
Guess there is more threads on it,
`Error: Failed to apply catalog: Execution of '/usr/bin/mysql -NBe SELECT CONCAT(User, '@',Host) AS User FROM mysql.user' returned 1: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: My manifest,
`class { '::mysql::server':
  root_password    => 'rootpassword',
  create_root_my_cnf => false,
  override_options => { 'mysqld' => { 'max_connections' => '1024' } }
}


mysql::db { 'mydb':
  user     => 'user',
  password => 'pass',
  host     => 'localhost',
  grant    => ['SELECT', 'UPDATE'],
} `

Comment: Also, I also tried your first manifest example,
`mysql_user { 'root@%': ensure => present, password_hash => mysql_password('rootpassword'), }`.
It does work in a way, doesn't create the file I think, creates the mysql root  user without any password. Means I can't login with just `mysql` command, but accepts an empty password with `mysql -u root -p`.
With this, it doesn't throw error while creating any further user,db combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and for me, creating a simple ~root/.my.cnf file fixed the problem. Add the following to the root .my.cnf file:

```
[client]
password="mysql root user password here"
```

This allows puppet to connect to mysql again. Puppet will then overwrite this file with its own generated configuration.